# How can i make my kubernetes dashboard accessible in my local network using my IP address or a local DNs

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, dashboard, kubectl, minikube

I have used kubectl proxy to access the kubernetes dashboard but i want to make it accessible now to my co-worker. 
Do i need a load balancer or there is a more efficient way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) resource, you can use those to expose multiple Services under the same IP address.

Another option are Services of type [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport). You can use those to expose a Service on a port of each Node in the cluster.